# WKWebView Text Shadow Removal

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have texts displayed inside `WKWebView` for some reason all texts have a shadow
that I didn't set and can't figure out how to remove it

[image]

Here is how I pass the data string with styles for the `webView`

```
let str = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira Sans Condensed' rel='stylesheet'> <style> body {font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';} .image {width: 100%; height: auto;} .bg-white { background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7); border-radius:40px; padding: 20px; }html { padding: 10px;} h2 {\(titleColor ?? "font-size:40pt; color:#000000;")} p{ font-size:26pt; {font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;}.bold{font-weight:bold;}.italic{font-style: italic;}.oblique{font-style: oblique;}} strong{font-size:30pt} </style> </head> <body><div class='bg-white'>\(htmlstr) </div> </body> </html>"
```

Tried but didn't work:

```
text-shadow:none;

div {-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
```

Does anybody know how to remove the shadow?

Comment: You need to give us a **reproducible** example. If I use `let htmlstr: String = "<p>geschieht</p>"` I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeY4w.png  If I change the `p{ font-size:26pt; ...` style in your `str` to `p{ font-size:86pt; ...` I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a6Jb.png

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your comment, since I'm not asking about font size.

Comment: I only changed the font size to make it bigger -- easier to see that there is NO shadow. That's why I said give us a **reproducible** example, since my quick test does not produce your image.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but my problem of the shadow being displayed when the texts are inside a WebView. I think some layer applies the unwanted shadows

Comment: Run this: https://pastebin.com/kvSdf9tH ... it uses the exact `let str = "<!DOCTYPE html> ...` string you posted, in a `WKWebView`. You will ***NOT*** see shadowing on the text. If you provide a ***reproducible example*** we can look at it and help you figure out where ***your*** "shadow" is coming from.

Comment: I just found out if I set webView.isOpaque = true the shadows are removed
However I need the webView to be isOpaque = false because I have partially transparent views. Any turnaround?

Comment: Updated example: https://pastebin.com/Jq9TmEM5 -- two `WKWebView` views, both with the same html string, top one has `.isOpaque = true` bottom one has `.isOpaque = false` -- this is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKv8u.png ... neither one has your "shadow." :: Jessica... I'm happy to help you figure this out, but for some reason ***you refuse to provide a reproducible example***. Do you really want to solve this?